# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'isUnAuthorizedError' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With the following structure:

```
ApiService.js
App.jsx
components/
          Tracks.jsx
          ...
```

This is my `ApiService.js`:

```
// ApiService.js   
import Axios from 'axios';

class ApiService {
  constructor() {
    this.axios = Axios.create();
    this.axios.interceptors.response.use(null, this.authInterceptor);

    this.get = this.axios.get.bind(this.axios);
    this.post = this.axios.post.bind(this.axios);
  }

  async authorize() {
    console.log('Async in authorize')
    const { accessToken } = await this.axios.post('/get_token/1', {});
    this.setAccessToken(accessToken);
    return accessToken; // return it to the component that invoked it to store in some state
  }

  async getAroma(userId, spotifyToken) {
    return this.axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/get-tracks/${userId}/${spotifyToken}`
    );
  }

  async updateAccessToken(userId) {
    const { accessToken } = await this.axios.post(`/refresh-token/1`, {});
    this.setAccessToken(accessToken);
  }

  async authInterceptor(error) {
    error.config.retries = error.config.retries || {
      count: 0,
    };

    if (this.isUnAuthorizedError(error) && this.shouldRetry(error.config)) {
      await this.updateAccessToken(); // refresh the access token
      error.config.retries.count += 1;

      return this.axios.rawRequest(error.config); // if succeed re-fetch the original request with the updated accessToken
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }

  isUnAuthorizedError(error) {
    return error.config && error.response && error.response.status === 401;
  }

  shouldRetry(config) {
    return config.retries.count < 3;
  }

  setAccessToken(accessToken) {
    this.axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`; // assign all requests to use new accessToken
  }
}

export const apiService = new ApiService(); // this is a single instance of the service, each import of this file will get it
```

And and instance of the service is being imported at my component `Track.jsx`, and called like so:

```
import {apiService} from '../ApiService';

....
async componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      const {userId, spotifyToken} = this.props;
      const aromaticTracks = await apiService.getTracks(userId, spotifyToken) ;
      this.setState({Tracks});
    } else {
      this.setState({Tracks: []});
      return null
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'isUnAuthorizedError' of undefined
```

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `authInterceptor` function is used as an callback function, the place where it is being invoked has set the context to be undefined i.e `this` will be undefined.

To fix this you can change `authInterceptor` function into an arrow function.

**Update**

Use `authInterceptor: async (error) => {` instead of `async authInterceptor(error) {`.

Alternatively you can also use bind method where you register your interceptor in constructor like `this.axios.interceptors.response.use(null, this.authInterceptor.bind(this));`

Comment: there are a few modes arrow functions could be used. could you please expand a bit o your answer and say how?

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand what modes are you talking about. But what I meant to say is context of an arrow function cannot be changed after creation so keyword this will always point to the instance of ApiService. I have updated the answer and also provided an alternate to arrow function.